# Is this inclusion-exclusion rule for counting elements of finite unions true?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

FYI 
[image]

> "For any finite set A, N(A) denotes the number of elements in A."

[image]

> "It can be shown using mathematical induction (see exercise 48 at the end of this section) that formulas analogous to those of Theorem 9.3.3 hold for unions of any finite number of sets."

[image]

Source: Discrete Mathematics With Applications, Susanna S. Epp

If we consider the theorem 9.3.3. is the same as the exercise 48, the right hand sides of $N(A_1 ∪ A_2)$ by theorem 9.3.3. and by the equation given in exercise 48 should be the same.

If n=2
$N(A_1\cup A_2) = [N(A_1)+N(A_2)] - N(A_1 ∩ A_2)$ $\color{blue}{\text{
By theorem 9.3.3.}}$

and

$N(A_1 ∪ A_2) = ∑ \limits_{1≤i≤2} N(A_i) - ∑ \limits_{1≤ i <j ≤ 2} N(A_i ∩ A_j) + ∑ \limits_{1≤i<j<k≤2} N(A_i ∩ A_j ∩ A_k) - \cdots + (-1)^{2+1} N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_2)$

"For all integers i with $1≤i≤2$" means integers 1, 2
"For all integers i, j with $1≤ i <j ≤ 2$" means integers i=1, j=2
"For all integers i, j, k with $1≤i<j<k≤2$" means integers i=1, j=2 and no integer k. hence $A_k= \emptyset$

= $ [N(A_1)+N(A_2)] - N(A_1 ∩ A_2) + N(A_i ∩ A_j ∩ Ø)- \cdots + (-1)^{2+1}N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩\cdots ∩A_2 $

= $ [N(A_1)+N(A_2)] - N(A_1 ∩ A_2) + 0 - \cdots - N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩\cdots ∩A_2)$
= $ [N(A_1)+N(A_2)] - 2N(A_1 ∩ A_2)$ $\color{blue}{\text{by the equation in exercise 48}}$

So the right hand side by the equation of exercise 48 is not the same as the right hand side of two sets in the equation theorem 9.3. when we substitute n=2 to
$N(A_1∪A_2 ∪\cdots ∪A_n)$
$\space\space\space  = ∑\limits_{1\le i \le k} N(A_i) - ∑\limits_{1≤i <j≤n} N(A_i ∩ A_j) + ∑\limits_{1≤ i <j<n} N(A_i ∩ A_j ∩ A_n) - \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} N(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ \cdots ∩ A_n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, no.   The ellipsis means "*continue* on in this pattern".   When $n=2$ there is no need to continue; the sequence is complete.   The last term was $N(A_1\cap A_2)$.   There is no need to repeat it.

$$\begin{align}N(A_1\cup A_2) = & N(A_1)+N(A_2)-N(A_1\cap A_2)
\\[3ex] N(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3) = & N(A_1)+N(A_2)+N(A_3)-N(A_1\cap A_2)\\ & -N(A_1\cap A_3)-N(A_2\cap A_3) + N(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)
\\[2ex]  = & \sum_{1\leq a\leq 3}N(A_a)-\sum_{1\leq a<b\leq 3}N(A_a\cap A_b) ~+~ N(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)
\\[3ex] N(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4) = & \sum_{1\leq a\leq 4}\!\!N(A_a)-\!\!\sum_{1\leq a<b\leq 4}\!\!N(A_a\cap A_b) \\ & +\!\!\!\!\sum_{1\leq a<b<c\leq 4}\!\!\!\! N(A_a\cap A_b\cap A_c)-N(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4)
\\[3ex] N(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5) = & \sum_{1\leq a\leq 5}\!\!N(A_a)-\!\!\sum_{1\leq a<b\leq 5}\!\!N(A_a\cap A_b) +\!\!\!\!\sum_{1\leq a<b<c\leq 5}\!\!\!\! N(A_a\cap A_b\cap A_c) \\ & -\!\!\!\!\sum_{1\leq a<b<c<d\leq 5}\!\!\!\! N(A_a\cap A_b\cap A_c\cap A_d)+N(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4\cap A_5)
\\[3ex] \textsf{et cetera}
\end{align}$$